# Is there a way to ask doctrine to propose conservative migrations?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm looking for a way to configure doctrine, so any migration proposed will be "conservative".
A conservative migration doesn't drop / rename any column or table, so any version of the code can run on the same DB.

I'm looking also a way to create a "breaking change" migration and mark it so anyone could recognize it

Comment: There is the [event system](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/events.html) you could probably hook into. The migrations would still be created, I think, but you could stop certain ones from running, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Chris Haas proposed in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73829004/is-there-a-way-to-ask-doctrine-to-propose-conservative-migrations#comment130365826_73829004) you could use doctrine event system. But I think it's a tough way.

More straightforward way is to keep those deleted/renamed fields in entity classes and mark them as deprecated until you decide to create "breaking change" migration.

Comment: Maybe I'll go this way. I think I'll need versioned entity properties. IE: use $foo until version v1.9, $bar from v2.0.